# Simple display date not show

Tags: jquery

My JavaScript not working.
Please give me solution.

`<button type="button" on click="getElementById('date').innarHTML=Date()">Click to show Date</button>
<p id="date"></p>`

Comment: Change innarHTML to innerHTML

Comment: @Happy new year , your spelling mistake to replace `innarHTML` to `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mistack of `innerHTML` as `innarHTML`. To change this correction for run your script.

```
<button type="button" on click="getElementById('date').innerHTML=Date()">Click to show Date</button>

<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for give me solution

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the spelling of `innerHTML` as `innarHTML`. Make the needed change and you should be good to go.

```
<button type="button" on click="getElementById('date').innerHTML=Date()">Click to show Date</button>

<p id="date"></p>
```